# Add a flat fee based on a category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found this php code on another thread. It adds a percentage fee per product to WooCommerce cart and checkout based on a category. I need to modify the code so that it adds a flat rate fee instead of a fee based on percent. I don't know php well enough to make the modifications so I would like to ask if one of the experts here would be kind enough to show me the code changes to make this happen?

It works fine expect it add percent instead of flat rate fee. Here is the code snippet:

```
function df_add_ticket_surcharge( $cart_object ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $specialfeecat = 33; // category id for the special fee
    $spfee = 0.00; // initialize special fee
    $spfeeperprod = 0.05; //special fee per product

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        $proid = $value['product_id']; //get the product id from cart
        $quantiy = $value['quantity']; //get quantity from cart
        $itmprice = $value['data']->price; //get product price

        $terms = get_the_terms( $proid, 'product_cat' ); //get taxonamy of the prducts
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $catid = $term->term_id;
                if($specialfeecat == $catid ) {
                    $spfee = $spfee + $itmprice * $quantiy * $spfeeperprod;
                }
            }
        endif;  
    }

    if($spfee > 0 ) {

        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Ticket Concierge Charge', $spfee, true, 'standard' );
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'df_add_ticket_surcharge' );
```

I've tried what little I know of php code as well as online searches without success. I'm hoping to find a solution here. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec for revising the question. I'm new here and I can use all the help I can get to make my post more understandable. Anyone have suggestions on revising the code to produce a flat rate?

Comment: Should the flat fee be added for each quantity of product, or should the flat be added, only one time for each product from corresponding category in woocommerce cart?

Comment: The fee should be added only one time for each product from corresponding category in woocommerce cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using is complicated and outdated. It can be highly simplified and updated for WooCommerce 3+.

As your question is not very clear, here are multiple cases *(variations)*:

1. Unique flat fee based on a category:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_ticket_concierge_fee' );
function add_ticket_concierge_fee( $cart ) {
    $terms = array( 33 ); // Here, set the targeted category(ies) id(s), slug(s) or name(s)
    $fee_amount = 5; // Here, set the flat fee amount (per item)
    $term_count = 0; // Initializing variable

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        // Check if the current item belongs to the targeted category(ies)
        if( has_term($terms, 'product_cat', $item['product_id']) ) {
            $term_count++;
        } 
    }

    if($term_count > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Ticket Concierge Charge', $fee_amount, true );
    }
}
```

2. Unique flat fee based on items count from a category:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_ticket_concierge_fee' );
function add_ticket_concierge_fee( $cart ) {
    $terms = array( 33 ); // Here, set the targeted category(ies) id(s), slug(s) or name(s)
    $fee_amount = 5; // Here, set the flat fee amount (per item quantity)
    $term_count = 0; // Initializing variable

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        // Check if the current item belongs to the targeted category(ies)
        if( has_term($terms, 'product_cat', $item['product_id']) ) {
            $term_count++;
        } 
    }

    if($term_count > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Ticket Concierge Charge', $fee_amount * $term_count, true );
    }
}
```

3. Unique flat fee based on items' quantity count from a category:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_ticket_concierge_fee' );
function add_ticket_concierge_fee( $cart ) {
    $terms = array( 33 ); // Here, set the targeted category(ies) id(s), slug(s) or name(s)
    $fee_amount = 5; // Here, set the flat fee amount
    $term_count = 0; // Initializing variable

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        // Check if the current item belongs to the targeted category(ies)
        if( has_term($terms, 'product_cat', $item['product_id']) ) {
            $term_count += $item['quantity'];
        } 
    }

    if($term_count > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Ticket Concierge Charge', $fee_amount * $term_count, true );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Your version #2 is exactly what I needed. The other two version will be helpful with other types of charges as well.

Comment: I'm sure others will find this useful as well. Thank you for your expertise and help. You truly are a wizard at this.